# How to interlace two char with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

My head is getting bad trying to find a solution for this assignment because my ideas didn't work...

I have to interlace two `char` strings using pointers. See the following example (this example is not code):

```
char s1 = "My House Black"
char s2 = "Are very near"
```

Result: `"MAyr eH ovuesrey  Bnleaacrk"`

How can I do this?

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. Show us where you're tripping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
int total = strlen(char1) + strlen(char2);
int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
for(i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        result[i] = char1[i1];
        i1++;
    }
    else
    {
        result[i] = char2[i2];
        i2++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint (pseudocode):

```
result = ""
for i = 0 to longest string's length:
    result += some character      (whose?)
    result += another character   (also, whose?)
```

Be careful: you need a little check somewhere, otherwise bad things might happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I will just give you an outline.

First of all declare your two strings:

```
const char *s1 = "My House Black";
const char *s2 = "Are very near";
```

Next declare two pointers to `char`:

```
char *p1 = s1;
char *p2 = s2;
```

Now enter a while loop. The condition should be that `*p1` or `*p2` are not equal to zero.

Inside the loop output `*p1` if it is not zero and then output `*p2` if it is not zero.  Increment each pointer if it refers to a non-zero character.

That's it, you are done!

Comment: Where is the memory declared for the output?

Comment: @Poodlehat I didn't declare an output string. The output could be to console (e.g. `printf`) for all I know.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged homework, I don't want to directly post code. But create three character arrays, one for each input, one long enough to contain the output, and traverse the input character arrays one character at a time (use pointer arithmetic). Store the character into your output string. Continue until you reach the end of each string. Don't forget the null terminations!

Answer (score 0):

You need a target string that is large enough to hold both input strings and the string terminator.

Then you should probably use a loop (`while` or `for`) where you copy one character from each input string in each iteration.

For extra credits:

Consider the case where the input strings are of unequal length.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
char * s1 = "My House Black";
char * s2 = "Are very near";

char * s = (char *)malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);

char * p1 = s1;
char * p2 = s2;
char * p = s;
while (*p1 && *p2)
{
    *p++ = *p1++;
    *p++ = *p2++;
}
while (*p1)
{
    *p++ = *p1++;
}
while (*p2)
{
    *p++ = *p2++;
}
*p = '\0';
```

Comment: This is a homework question. You are not supposed to do homework for the student. Please read the [faq] and look at the homework tag description.

Comment: @user997683 1.  "Doesn't work" is plain rude. 2. It does work and is infact the canonical solution to your problem. 3. When you said you did not want code, just ideas, were you being honest?